# ObjC -> Swift Conversion Error: For-in loop requires '[AnyHashable : Any]?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am struggling with converting this for loop from ObjC to Swift

Obj C Code

```
NSMutableDictionary *varnameDict;
for(NSString *varName in [varnameDict allKeys]) { ... }
```

Converting to Swift 5

```
 var varNameDict: [AnyHashable : Any]?
 for varName in varnameDict{...}
```

The error I get at for in loop line is:
For-in loop requires '[AnyHashable : Any]?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?

I have also tried the following:

```
for varName in varnameDict?.keys ?? [] {...}
```

I get the following error:

Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>.Keys?' to expected argument type 'Optional<_>'

I don't have an extensive background here. I would appreciate any help or direction.

Comment: start by changing your dictionary declaration to non optional and initialize it win an empty dictionary `var nameDict: [AnyHashable : Any] = [:]`

Comment: Do you really need the keys of your dictionary to be `AnyHashable`? You generally only need `String`

Comment: to iterate your dictionary `for (key, value) in nameDict { print(key,value) }`

Comment: The main issue is that you are trying to supply a default value (an empty array) to your optional dictionary `for varName in varNameDict ?? [:] { \\ your code }` Note that `varName will be a keyValue tuple` so it would be easier if you deconstruct it in your for loop `for (key, value) in varNameDict ?? [:] { }`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your suggestions. Appreciate the help.